# Compose key sequences for Ǝ and ə?

Tags: escape-characters

`/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` (Ubuntu 18.04) defines compose sequences for accented variations of the turned "e" character:

```
<dead_acute> <U018E>                    : "Ǝ́"   # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED E WITH ACUTE
<dead_grave> <U018E>                    : "Ǝ̀"   # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED E WITH GRAVE
<dead_circumflex> <U018E>               : "Ǝ̂"   # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED E WITH CIRCUMFLEX
<dead_caron> <U018E>                    : "Ǝ̌"   # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED E WITH CARON
<dead_macron> <U018E>                   : "Ǝ̄"   # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED E WITH MACRON
<dead_tilde> <U018E>                    : "Ǝ̃"   # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED E WITH TILDE
<dead_acute> <dead_tilde> <U018E>       : "Ǝ̃́"   # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED E WITH TILDE AND ACUTE
<dead_grave> <dead_tilde> <U018E>       : "Ǝ̃̀"   # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER TURNED E WITH TILDE AND GRAVE

<dead_acute> <U01DD>                    : "ǝ́"   # LATIN SMALL LETTER TURNED E WITH ACUTE
<dead_grave> <U01DD>                    : "ǝ̀"   # LATIN SMALL LETTER TURNED E WITH GRAVE
<dead_circumflex> <U01DD>               : "ǝ̂"   # LATIN SMALL LETTER TURNED E WITH CIRCUMFLEX
<dead_caron> <U01DD>                    : "ǝ̌"   # LATIN SMALL LETTER TURNED E WITH CARON
<dead_macron> <U01DD>                   : "ǝ̄"   # LATIN SMALL LETTER TURNED E WITH MACRON
<dead_tilde> <U01DD>                    : "ǝ̃"   # LATIN SMALL LETTER TURNED E WITH TILDE
<dead_acute> <dead_tilde> <U01DD>       : "ǝ̃́"   # LATIN SMALL LETTER TURNED E WITH TILDE AND ACUTE
<dead_grave> <dead_tilde> <U01DD>       : "ǝ̃̀"   # LATIN SMALL LETTER TURNED E WITH TILDE AND GRAVE
```

but strangely, it doesn't define a sequence for the character itself.

It doesn't even define the similar characters (U+2203 ∃ "there exists") and (U+0259 ə "schwa").

**Is there some sequence for these characters (Ǝ U+018E, and ǝ U+01DD), or do I have to define it myself in my ~/.XCompose file?**

And if not, *why* aren't they defined along with the accented versions?

Comment: should there be any deep reason for that? `ə` is defined as multi_key+e+e on my system (Debian Buster). Another 5 releases from now, and you will have the whole set ;-)

Comment: @UncleBilly, it just seems very strange to go to the trouble of providing a character with both a tilde and a grave accent at the same time, but not the unaccented character itself.  Which one are people going to need more frequently?

Comment: They probably generated that automatically.

Comment: Doesn't `shift-ctrl-u 18e<enter>` work for you? Repeating e generates an ə in compose.

Comment: @Isaac, yes, but that's only a work-around.  Why would compose sequences be provided for almost never used variations of a character, but not the original character itself?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu the sequence for the character itself is <kbd>Compose</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>.

[The Wikipedia article on Ə](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C6%8F) has more information.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. I wonder if that is a relatively new addition; I didn't see it when I was running 18.04.

Comment: But there is still this oddity in 20.04: `grep -i exist /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` still finds only `<Multi_key> <U2203> <U0338>  : "∄"   U2204 # THERE DOES NOT EXIST`.  Why define "does not exist" but not "does exist"?